# How to set a column in gridview as hyperlink and click on ID data able to point to other to show data details in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I tried many work around but unable to set the column as hyperlink. This is the output i get.
[Output that i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCBOX.png)

I want to add the hyperlink as below screenshot:

[Output with hyperlink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhL3j.png)

[Click on that link able to show the detail as below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTm0u.png)

This is my code but i unable to add hyperlink:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White"
        runat = "server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="OnDataBound" GridLines="Both">      
        <Columns>  
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LOT" HeaderText="LOT" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="TYPE" HeaderText="TYPE" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="KEY" HeaderText="KEY" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="VALUE" HeaderText="VALUE" ItemStyle-Width="150" />             
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind that i have done:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepickerstart.Text);
        string Date = StartDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");

        DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datepicker.Text);
        string dt2 = EndDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        
        GridView1.DataSource = GetData("Oracle query");
        GridView1.DataBind();

    
        txtDate.Text = "You Selected Start:" + Date;
        txtDate1.Text = "You Selected End:" + EndDate;
        

    }

    private DataTable GetData(string query)
    {
        string oradb = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =" +
    "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = '')(PORT = ''))" +
    "(CONNECT_DATA =" +
    "(SERVER = DEDICATED)" +
    "(SERVICE_NAME = '')" +
     ")" +
     ");User ID='';Password='';";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
    protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int rowIndex = GridView1.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
            GridViewRow previousRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

            if (row.Cells[0].Text == previousRow.Cells[0].Text)
            {
                row.Cells[0].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan < 2 ? 2 :
                                       previousRow.Cells[0].RowSpan + 1;
                previousRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Bound Field you need to use TemplateField > ItemTemplate > LinkButton just i have used below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#3AC0F2" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" runat = "server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDataBound="OnDataBound" GridLines="Both">      
 <Columns>  
       
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action">
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="btnIdLink" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LOT" HeaderText="LOT" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TYPE" HeaderText="TYPE" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="KEY" HeaderText="KEY" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="VALUE" HeaderText="VALUE" ItemStyle-Width="150" />             
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried to used your method but when the data return is the wrong one.

Comment: Hi noobprogrammer, i run the code it only return me with one ID and i can't find the reason why. It suppose return me with 2 ID with bthIdlink. Thanks

Comment: @Yong check your database. Does it have ID values? Make sure ID is not null in your database.

Comment: Hi @noobprogrammer, I checked my database side there is no issue on that, ID column not null. I’m not sure is because I adding “protected void OnDataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) -> I only want Merge same value in ID column only” so caused Only return me one ID? Thanks